# How to start Home Assistant Code stopped from web UI

Tags: home-assistant

I am unable to start Home Assistant Core running on docker post it is stopped from "Server Controls" in web UI.

Comment: It seems like adding --net=host on docker creates issue with home assistant start-up

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: restart the host. If I'm not wrong, by default, HA restarts with the host.

If that does not work, you can start your docker container.
Run: `docker ps -a` to get the list of all available containers. Identify the HA one. You should have something like this:

```
afa90071dd81        homeassistant/intel-nuc-homeassistant:0.118.5   "/init"                  13 hours ago        Up 13 hours                                                                                  homeassistant
ac4fe3306d98        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-supervisor           "/init"                  13 hours ago        Up 13 hours                                                                                  hassio_supervisor
```

(note that the status should be `stopped` in your case).
Then, you just need to start your HA container.
In the example case, that requires `docker start homeassistant` or `docker start afa90071dd81`.

Comment: Thank you both. Basically, restarting the container kept failing. When checked the container logs, it was like the config file was broken. Hence had to re-install the container.